# Transposing (or pivoting but not aggregating) a name/value column pair

Tags: powerquery, m

I have a data set imported into PQ/Excel from XML that has this form-

```
Type     Name      Value
measure  name      depth
measure  svmbol    d
measure  value     Fathom
measure  name      width
measure  svmbol    w
measure  value     metre
measure  property  Length
```

The data shape is clear and quite structured, although the number of attributes does vary from 3 to 5 per item (measure).

I want to transform the name/value pairs in the second two columns into a table form-

```
Type     Name      Symbol  Value   Property
measure  depth     d       fathom
measure  width     w       metre   Length
```

Seems as if it should be simple, but `Transpose` wants to transpose the whole table only, while `Pivot` of the *Name* column, which looks like the right tool, either wants to aggregate (count) the data, which is no use to me, or fails if you choose the "do not aggregate" option with the error "too many elements in the enumeration".

I think I could achieve the result, laboriously, by creating four custom columns with logic in them, but that seems excessive. Is there a way to use Pivot or other functions to do this easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a unique counter that changes each time [Name]=name before pivoting

Add column .. Index column

Add column .. Custom Column ... with formula

```
if [Name]="name" then [Index] else null
```

Right click the new custom column and fill down

Right click the index column and Remove it

Click the name column then Transform ... Pivot column ... value column is Value and in Advanced choose Dont Aggregate

Right click the extra column and remove it

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index1", "Custom", each if [Name]="name" then [Index] else null),
#"Filled Down1" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filled Down1",{"Index"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Name]), "Name", "Value")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: Thats's it. I had cobbeled together something that did roughly this in a roundabout way, but this is simpler and cleaner. I shall update my query to this form.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If it works, please accept the answer  by clicking the "check mark" underneath the vote buttons, so that it turns green